# How do I find out if a critical point of a function is a maximum or a minimum?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

If I've found the critical point of a function defined in some constraint (perhaps using Lagrange multipliers and the like); how do I find out if it's a relative/global maximum/minimum of a function without plugging it into an equation and/or using the second-derivative test (considering an example of a one-degree polynomial)?

I'd like an example too if that's not too much.

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks for the link; but it doesn't help much either -- I'm talking about a one-degree polynomial

Comment: You can plot it.